# How to print an arrayList in Java, printing "last in - first out"

Tags: java, arraylist

So this is my problem/question:

The assignment is to write a program which takes in n-amounts of Strings, which are words or a sentence, then prints out the strings, by a "last in, first out"-method and counting the words in this sentence. This is my code so far, but how can I print the last x inputs?

```
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Moment2
    {
        public static void main (String [] args)
        {
            String indata;
            int count;
            indata = showInputDialog("Hur många strängar ska räknas?");
            count = Integer.parseInt(indata);
        StringHandlerY lastword = null;

        while (true) {
            ArrayList<String> mening = new ArrayList<String>();
            String ord = showInputDialog("Skriv ett ord eller en mening. Annars, tryck 'Cancel'. ");
              if (ord == null) {
                break;
              }
              else {
                //count ++;
                mening.add(ord);
                lastword = new StringHandlerY(ord);
              }
            }
            print(lastword, count);
            }

          public static void print(StringHandlerY lastWord, int stringCount) {
              showMessageDialog(null, "Du tryckte 'cancel' \nDu har givit "+stringCount+" strängar."
                    + "\nSträngen: \n'" + lastWord.getString() +"', har "+ lastWord.getWords() + " ord");

          }
        }
```

// this is in a different file:

```
public class StringHandlerY 
{
    static int nrOfObjects;
    private String str;

    // konstruktor
    StringHandlerY (String s) {
        str = s;
    }
    // accessor / getters - returnan nÃ¥gonting
    int getWords () {
        String[] temp = this.str.split(" ");
        int i = temp.length;
        return i;
    }
    String getString () {
        return this.str;
    }
}**strong text**
```

Comment: Take a look at [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

Comment: Consider using a Stack rather if you do require a arrayList as that is part of the assignment, check out the Deque interface for some useful methods.

Answer (score 1):

latestStringTry stack which is already present and allows removal of last element:

```
 Stack<String> stringStack = new Stack<String>();
 stringStack.push("Hello World");
 stringStack.push("Hi World");
 String latestString = stringStack.pop();
 System.out.println("Last string was " + latestString + " with size " + latestString.split("\\s+").length);
```

If you want to stick with List then try LinkedList as below:

```
LinkedList<String> stringList = new LinkedList<String>();
stringList.add("Hello World");
stringList.add("Hi World");
String latestString = stringList.removeLast();
System.out.println("Last string was " + latestString + " with size "
            + latestString.split("\\s+").length);
```

Answer (score 0):

use ListIterator , this iterator allows us to iterate in both direction. Iterator has methods like has

previous()
Returns the previous element in the list and moves the cursor position backwards.

hasPrevious()
Returns true if this list iterator has more elements when traversing the list in the reverse direction.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html

Sample code : http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/arraylist/arraylist-listiterator-example/

Comment: I think I'm supposed to use stacks, not positive since the questions are all in Swedish...